# Share attachment and text from metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on a metro app with c#. I want to share some attachment with subject and mail body to mailto application.
I code like this

```
DataRequest request = args.Request;
DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
request.Data.Properties.Title = Constants.EMAIL_SUBJECT;
request.Data.SetText(Constants.EMAIL_TEXT);
smiFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(Constants.SMI_FILE);

List<IStorageItem> lstItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
lstItems.Add(smiFile);
if (lstItems.Count > 0)
{
    request.Data.SetStorageItems(lstItems);
}

deferral.Complete();
```

When I open mailto app in share charm it only shows attachment with blank subject and body. And in second scenario if I remove attachment then subject and body appears. Why this is happening I want complete mail to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because Mail app has limitation. I think Microsoft should update Mail app with that sharing capability. Check these also.

[Share attachment and text from metro app](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/8997820e-a393-478d-a461-6335e5741886) (I think this is your thread :P)

[How to set subject and message part in email with attachment while share charm usage ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3478925a-0945-4037-9bbf-4fc7ef6595c5)